# my maiden post: Having trouble with ind2rgb function in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, contour

A breif disclaimer: I am self-taught programmer, and this is officially my first stack overflow post, so try and be patient.

I have a 250X250 probability distribution(pdf) matrix (values ranging 0 to 1) which I would like to turn into a true-color (250x250x3) matrix so i can save a series of these matrices and display them as a movie or save them as an RGB image.  My question is two-fold:

First, if I use:

```
cmp=jet;
img=ind2rgb(pdf,cmp);
```

whereas imagesc(pdf) returns proper heat map figure I would expect, img ends up being a completely blue image, with `img(:,:,3)=(some value<1)` and `(img(:,:,1:2)==0`.
I would be really grateful if someone could explain why `ind2rgb()` isn't (scaling?) the same way `imagesc()` is, and how I would go about fixing that.

Additionally:

I know `contour()` and `imagesc()` are helpful functions for displaying these indexed values in a matlab figure window, but is there any way to save a matlab figure as a true-color image *without* the figure axis?

An answer to either or both of these questions would be appreciated.

Colin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ind2rg doesn't scale the image, it only maps it to the colormap. You have to scale the image yourself. Also, you'll need to specify the size of the colormap. Here's an example:

```
pdf = rand(100,100); % fake data
pdfScaled = uint8(256*pdf); % scale data
cmp = jet(256); % 256 element colormap
img = ind2rgb(pdfScaled,cmp);

subplot(2,1,1)
imagesc(pdf)
title('indexed image')
subplot(2,1,2)
image(img) 
title('rgb image')
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image: indexed and rgb images]

As to your second questions, `getframe` and `imwrite` can be used to save the image as it is displayed in an axis. For example:

```
figure
imagesc(spiral(10))
frame = getframe();
imwrite(frame.cdata, 'frame.png')
```

Comment: Thanks Molly, that helped. sorry for the delayed response. i read the post, fixed my code, and promptly forgot about responding.